# Passing value from <li> and option value

Tags: javascript, html

I asked for help earlier and got it working correct which i'm very thankfull for. But now I have wanted to make some more indepth.

My problem is that, I have a `<li>` which is used as a dropdown, which later opens a body where theres a select, and option value which I put a url value into.

But I rather have it look on which `<li>` I first pick, and then depending on which option value I use adds more value so I get a complete url.

Example: 
`<li>` sets `http://localhost/someplace/api/stop/`
and the option value sets ~/api/stop/all?format=excel because I picked excel format as option.

Then I have a js with button which does

```
$(".get-data").on("click",function() {
  var location = $('#dd-files').val();
  if(location) {
    window.open(location);
  }
});
```

But how do I pass the `<li>` value and option value picks into this.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an onclick event to the list items and then use $(this) to get the text or to get the name or id or whatever you want.

```
$('#dd li').click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32ZEx/

Does this help you?

Comment: Sortof, but how do I implement my js click function with this too? So it lists both that value and my `$(".get-data").on("click",function() {
  var location = $('#dd-files').val();
  if(location) {
    window.open(location);
  }
});`

Which takes the option value picked.

Answer (score 0):

U can get `li` value as following:

HTML :

```
<li class="selected">Value</li>
```

JS:

```
$("li.selected").text(); // gives u the text inside li
```

Comment: Yes but if I want to pass that value into a specific url, heres one of my li which is picked when pressed.
`<li><a id='stop' data-name='' href='#'>StopValue</a></li>` but I dont get how I make that specific `<li>` to remember that its picked when finally pressing a option value later on and combine those two. I was thinking like var finalurl = 'li-picked + location' and use it in the (if).